# How to let user download -in backend generated- CSV file from frontend?

Tags: java, json, database, csv, export

I am currently working on a web application. I created a button called "export", in the front end. A user click should trigger the download of a CSV file, which I generated in the back end. The CSV file is filled with values from a database table.

Do I need to generate a link to pass it to the front end button (maybe with JSON?)?
How should I proceed?

Additional information: The application is programmed with Java. The framework I use is Spring-Boot.

**Code for generating CSV file**

```
public class readDb {

    public static List<Success> getDataFromDb (List<Success> success){

        System.out.println("getDataFromDb");
        erfolg.forEach(System.out::println);
        return erfolg;

    }

public static void successExport (List<Success> success) throws IOException {

    String csvFile = "\\\\fs-vcs-02\\userhome\\username\\Desktop\\test.csv";
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(csvFile);


    CSVUtils.writeLine(writer, Arrays.asList("id", "endDate", "dataFromB", "dataToB", "dataToE", "report", "amountOfM", "rate", "amountOfA", "statistics", "resultP", "resultN", "resultO", "chancel", "assignmentVolume));

    for (Erfolg d : erfolg) {

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(d.getId().toString());
        list.add(d.getEndDate().toString());
        list.add(d.getDataFromB().toString());
        list.add(d.getDataToB().toString());
        list.add(d.getDataToE().toString());
        list.add(d.getReport().toString());
        list.add(d.getAmountOfM().toString());
        list.add(d.getRate().toString());
        list.add(d.getAmountOfA().toString());
        list.add(d.getStatistics().toString());
        list.add(d.getResultP().toString());
        list.add(d.getResultN().toString());
        list.add(d.getResultO().toString());
        list.add(d.getChancel().toString());
        list.add(d.getAssignmentVolume().toString());


        CSVUtils.writeLine(writer, list);
    }

    writer.flush();
    writer.close();

    }
}
```

**Code for file export**

```
public static void export() {
    File f = null;
    boolean bool = false;

    try {
        f = new File("\\\\fs-vcs-02\\userhome\\agoenkur\\Desktop\\test.csv");
        bool = f.createNewFile();
        System.out.println("File created: "+bool);

        f.delete();
        System.out.println("delete() method is invoked");

        bool = f.createNewFile();
        System.out.println("File created: "+bool);

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```